# How do you create a UIImageView that pops up from a set position and then hide it when it is touched and then the next image can pop up

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, popup

I have tried using Cocos2d for this but I can't seem to figure out any code that does exactly what I want it to do as what I want it to do is quite specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would use `CCSprite` for the image, initialize it with `scale = 0` and animate scaling of the sprite. When touched animate it back to 0.

Show what you have tried ... and if you need more pointers I'll gladly help.

Comment: I tried using this code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029975/pop-up-animation-in-cocos2d-game

Comment: it did not, it was not helpful with what i am trying to do

Comment: If you are new to cocos2d maybe you should look at simple examples and try to continue it from there. Without the basic concepts it will be hard to achieve what you are trying to do. (And yes it is possible :) )

Comment: thanks, as long as i know it is possible cocos2d is the way to go with my app